# Checkout 'hanging' in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I installed Magento 2 with Softaculous successfully. I only added code to .local host in Magento root for running 3 stores based on the same Magento installation (taking the code out does not make any difference to the issue below).

On 2 of my stores, after adding to cart and clicking "Go to Checkout' the screen only displays the 'logo and the 'order summary' without the 'shipping' step, see
https://babyplus.com.my/checkout 
Same for my Contoursbaby (Malaysia) website.

On the third store however it consistently works fine, running the SAME Magento installation: https://babyfair.com.my/checkout

'Checkout with PayPal' works fine on all websites.

I had a well-known Magento extension developer have a look at this, however they could not find the solution.

Some background info: the website runs on shared hosting on Litespeed Server. We had to run *php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy* to make images appear.

Comment: Did you check any javascript error? Can you delete var/cache/*, var/page_cache/*, pub/static/*, var/composer_home/*, var/view_preprocessed/* and run deploy command?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution @sohel rana : the following Javascript errors on the checkout pages:

/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/element/region.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'is_region_required' of undefined

ONLY occurs on the websites with the checkout problem, i.e. babyplus.com.my and contoursbaby.com.my, NOT on babyfair.com.my
/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_PageCache/js/page-cache.js:40 Uncaught TypeError: element.prop is not a function
occurs on ALL the websites

Comment: I believe it is a bug, similar to https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1508

Answer (score 2):

Solved, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2933 as suggested by ***@srynot4sale***

Fix was to enable the country specified in the `"Default Tax Destination -> Default Country" in "Country Options -> Allowed Countries"`